# Azure Powershell, Get-AzureVM returning nothing

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a Azure Cloud Service (classic).

Get-AzureService gives results

But there's no response when I try
 Get-AzureVM -ServiceName mytestservice

If I type in the wrong servicename
 Get-AzureVM -ServiceName mynonexistingservice
I get a 
 warning: WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'mynonexistingservice'.

I tried running powershell as administrator as well

Comment: `Get-AzureVM` is for Virtual Machines, not cloud services. Your web/worker role instances won't be retrieved with that call.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the correct command is: Get-AzureRole